# Conversion of Javascript Fetch request to Angular Http client not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, httprequest, ionic4

I am trying to access truelayer client API using Angular HttpClient. The request works fine for the Sandbox API, however, I get 'internal_server_error' for the live environment API. Below is my Httpclient code

```
this.http.post<tokentype>('https://auth.truelayer.com/connect/token',{'grant_type':'authorization_code','client_id':'<my-id>','client_secret':'<my-client-secret>','redirect_uri':'<my-redirect-url>','code':'<access-code>'}, {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Tye':"application/json; charset=utf-8"})})
       .subscribe(data => {
         console.log('Token Finally Gotten 1:');
         console.log(data);      
        }, error => {
        console.log('Error 1: ' + JSON.stringify(error))
       });
```

when I change the Url to `https://auth.truelayer-sandbox.com/connect/token`, it works fine. Below is the jQuery code I got from Truelayer Postman

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://auth.truelayer.com/connect/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_id": "",
    "client_secret": "",
    "redirect_uri": "https://console.truelayer.com/redirect-page",
    "code": ""
  }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems some parameter mismatch. Please verify if you are entering correct values for clientid, credentials, redirecturl etc. with respect to live environment and not sandbox.